# CNF/ Create a cnf variable from some forumals of CNF

Tags: logic, algorithms

I have the next CNF: $(A \lor C) \land (B \lor C)$

and also: $(D \lor E) \land (F \lor G)$

Now, I want to be sure that only one of the CNF is true.

Meaning, I want to declare two new variable, T and S, when T = $(A \lor C) \land (B \lor C)$, and S = $(D \lor E) \land (F \lor G)$, and than be sure that only one of them is satisfied (using at most one and at least one methods).

My problem is that I don't know how decalre S and T as new CNF variable.

Any help?

Comment: What happened when $A,B,C$ are not all true?

Comment: @BabakS.: I think I don't unserstand your question. IF A, B, C are not all true, than the other CNF need be satisified. For example, D & F would be true.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I am assuming you want something like `S XOR T`: $S \oplus T$.

This is equivalent to $T \lor S \land \lnot (T \land S)$:

To get this in CNF:

$$T \lor S \land \lnot (T \land S) \equiv (T \lor S) \land (\lnot T \lor \lnot S)\tag{1}$$

Now, if we want to express this using your assignments of $T = (A \lor C) \land (B \lor C)$ and $S=(D \lor E) \land (F \lor G)$, we get, by substitution into the right-hand side of $(1)$:

$$ \lbrace[(A \lor C) \land (B \lor C)] \lor [(D \lor E) \land (F \lor G)]\rbrace \land \lbrace \lnot[(A \lor C) \land (B \lor C)] \lor \lnot[(D \lor E) \land (F \lor G)]\rbrace\tag{2}$$

Let me know if you need help with changing $(2)$ into CNF, and/or if I've misunderstood your question altogether!

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that there can be more than 2 varaibles (S, T, Q, and more..). For that, I prefer to give for each cnf it varaible, and then use these variables in the way that would promise that only one of them is satisifed. So, I search a way to write cnf that would reflect the next forumla: T= (my cnf). Then, I would use T (and for that point, I know what to do). Thanks.